# Xamarin.Forms Portable won't start on Marshmallow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I had a project I was working on and debugging as a UWP. I also want it to run on Android and it was working fine on the standard MS image for 5" Lollipop (5.0) XXHDPI Phone emulator." My personal phone is a Moto G3 however. It runs Marshmallow. I tried packaging and deploying to my phone and it failed to start. So I downloaded an emulator for 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone, which is similar to my physical phone and got the same issue. The OnCreate method in MainActivity isn't even being called. A white screen flashes up and disappears and the app terminates. After a couple days of attempting to find a solution I punted and created a brand new Xamarin.Forms Portable app. I have added no code and have made no changes at all. This project is straight from the template. Same issue! It runs on Lollipop emulator, but not the Marshmallow emulator and not my Moto G3 physical phone. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your environment: Which version of Xamarin and Xamarin.Android you are using. Also which version of Xamarin Forms are you using?

Comment: Xamarin 4.2 (Forms and Android) in VS 2015 Professional.  I'm running a fully updated version of Windows 10.  All I did was choose New Project/Cross-Platform/Blank XAML App (Xamarin.Forms Portable).  After it finished creating the blank template app I started the VS Android Emulator for the 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone Api Level 23 and started the app targeting that emulator.  I haven't written a single line of code beyond what the initial template provided.  It fails against Marshmallow and succeeds against Lollipop.  No error or anything, it just flashes a white screen and terminates.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, Xamarin.Forms 2.3 and Xamarin.Android I think is 24.2.1.  It says an update is available but Nuget fails to update the Support libraries.  The docs say to leave the update alone and it'll get updated automatically.

Comment: Forms relies on specific versions of the Android support libraries, thus why you can not update the support libraries. You can update Forms package and the Support libraries will be updated if needed, but it seems you are up to date. I am going to try to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I can reproduce the issue using the VS Android emulator. Issue seems to be that the debugger is not connecting. However a new template forms app does deploy and debug to the Google x86 HAXM emulators. To resolve the issue with the VS emulators on my end I had to follow the trouble shooting steps at:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/#App_deploys_and_starts_but_fails_immediately

> 1. Click the Start button, type in MMC, and press Enter. Click Hyper-V Manager as illustrated here:
> 2. In the Hyper-V Manager Virtual Machines pane, right click the emulator that you are trying to use and click Settings...":
> 3. In the settings window, locate the Compatibility section (under Hardware > Processor) and enable Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version:
> 4. Click OK and close the Hyper-V Manager window.

Comment: That got the test app running just fine.  It also helped me figure out what was going on with my real app on my actual phone.  Thanks for the help on this one!

Comment: Glad I could help!